# Best practice for making component with rich content clickable?

Tags: react-native

There is a button component that looks good on both Android and iOS out of the box. I think it uses a combination of TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback based on OS.

Say I have a custom component with rich content, like a card containing image and text, and I want to make the entire component clickable.

Is there any best practice for how to do this so that is looks nice on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your entire component with `TouchableOpacity`, it works well on both platforms. This component can be styled just the same as the `View` component.